# RefreshControl implementation iOS and Android platforms

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, pull-to-refresh

I am very new to React Native programming. I am trying to implement a pull to refresh functionality in a ListView. So, I decided to use [RefreshControl](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol.html) Component. I have implemented the variable states and functions according to the document, but the **_onRefresh()** function is never getting called. Hence, progress bar is also not appearing on the top.

My source code:

```js
// @flow
'use strict';

import React, {Component} from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Image,
  Text,
  ListView,
  TouchableHighlight,
  RefreshControl,
} from "react-native";

var BookingRow = require('./bookingRow');
var RequestRow = require('./requestRow');

class Bookings extends Component {
  state: {
    dataSource: Object;
    //refreshing: false,
  };
  ds: Object;

  static propTypes = {
    authKey: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    endpoints: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    profile: React.PropTypes.object,
    optionalBookings: React.PropTypes.array,
    optionalRequests: React.PropTypes.array,
    translator: React.PropTypes.object,
    rowSelected: React.PropTypes.func,
  };

  constructor(props: Object) {
    super();
    this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    var set;
    if (typeof props.bookings !== 'undefined') {
      set = props.bookings;
    } else {
      set = props.requests;
    }
    this.state = {
      dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(set),
      refreshing: false
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props: Object) {
    var set;
    if (typeof props.bookings !== 'undefined') {
      set = props.bookings;
    } else {
      set = props.requests;
    }
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(set)
    });
  }

  _onRefresh() {
    console.log("_onRefresh");
    this.setState({refreshing: true});
    this.props.fetchBookings().then(() => {
      this.setState({refreshing: false});
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.refreshing);
    return (
      <ListView
      refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
            //onRefresh={() => this.props.fetchBookings()}
          />
        }
        dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
        enableEmptySections = {true}
        renderRow = {(rowData) => {
          if (typeof this.props.bookings !== 'undefined') {
            return (
              <BookingRow
                endpoints = {this.props.endpoints}
                authKey = {this.props.authKey}
                booking = {rowData}
                profile = {this.props.profile}
                translator = {this.props.translator}
                rowPicked = {() => this.props.rowSelected(rowData)}
              />
            );
          } else {
            return (
              <RequestRow
                profile = {this.props.profile}
                endpoints = {this.props.endpoints}
                authKey = {this.props.authKey}
                request = {rowData}
                translator = {this.props.translator}
                rowPicked = {() => this.props.rowSelected(rowData)}
              />
            );
          }
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});

module.exports = Bookings;
```

Where am I going wrong? Is there any prop that I have missed? What should I do to ensure that the pull gesture is detected by the ListView?

Comment: I have a very similar implementation that works as intended, but the big difference is I've used `FlatList` instead of `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

This is best tool to search for 3rd party libraries(module) for react-native as well: (This link searched for pull to refresh module for the react-native you can search any query for modules)

https://js.coach/react-native/react-native-simple-auth?search=pull[enter link description here](https://js.coach/react-native/react-native-simple-auth?search=pull)

**Note:** You can integrate these module for refresh functionality. Also see the compatibility with the iOS and Android as well before implementing.
Sometime it says that the module works for both iOS and Android. To be sure try to run the example app(available in the github section in example folder of the same repo)